# What does the throbber speed indicate in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Based on a lifetime of using web browsers, I expect that when a browser has an active [throbber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber), it's downloading a page.  I've never seen multiple throbbers, though, and I just noticed that Chrome has (at least) two.

Out of five open tabs, three were static and just sitting open in the background, so they displayed [favicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) as expected.  The other two were loading, but one had a slow counter-clockwise throbber while the other had a fast clockwise throbber.  What's the difference between the two (and any others that may exist)?

**Update**:
Firefox 4 has been released, and it has the same behavior (or at least a similar-looking behavior). I still haven't found documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've always assumed that the slow anti-clockwise throbber was indicating that an http request had been sent, and once data started to be received back it changed to the faster clockwise version.

Multiple tabs, multiple requests, hence separate throbbers.

Comment: This seems reasonable, do you know of any documentation for it?

Comment: I also assumed that and have noticed that when it is spinning counter-clockwise it takes longer to load a page, and as you suggested, when the data starts to come back it loads clockwise and faster. Also, sandboxing would explain the separate throbbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I think it’s like

Backwards:
Chrome: “hey Wikipedia, I want to visit your page”

Wikipedia: *notices Chrome’s call*

Goes forward

Wikipedia: Here is the page Chrome

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).